# I get 404 error when refreshing page (Angular - Cpanel)

Tags: angular, https, http-status-code-404, cpanel

I uploaded to production my first Angular project.  When I refresh the page I get an error message. It also happens when I type in the address field the exact route. It happens with every route that I try. Error message Are :

"Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

What is the solution?

Comment: supply more details: full error message and the configuration of your deployment and routing system

Comment: I think it's complicated to directly see the concern you have without having an environment to analyze. I recommend that you create a simple app with your piece of code.

Comment: Can you provide more details: deployment process, whaere did you deploy the application and configurations.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.